# Datasource RowFilter behaviour

Tags: vb.net

I have a question regarding `RowFilter`. How this works exactly?

From my understanding when `datasource` is bound to data and when I use `RowFilter` towards fields within that datassource it should just filter the datasource result. For example, in `DataGridView` or `ListBox` or whatever.

If I take for example `DataGridView` and have some `Checkbox` type column, if I check some checkboxes for some of rows and do the `RowFilter` my checkboxes going to be unchecked automatically. Why is such behaviour behind? Shouldn't it just filter instead of changing something in GUI?

Simple code:

```
   myGrid.DataSource = _gridData.GetDataSet()

    myGrid.Tables(0).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("[Nummer] like '" & txt1.Text.Trim() & "%'")  

myGrid.Tables(0).DefaultView.Sort = " DateRequested DESC "
```

Comment: Yes, it should just filter the current state of the data but I suspect you are going back to the database? Show the relevant code where you filter and bind.

Comment: @Crowcoder Code shown. Does it mean in this case that Datasource is 'not touched' - means RowFilter and Sort do just a filter based on current dataset but is not quering database again taking data based on filter? Am i right?

Comment: To me it looks like `GetDataSet()` makes a database call. Unless you save changes first, your local data will be overwritten regardless of what the user has done. I can't tell for sure without seeing more of your code, but I think what you want is to add a `DataColumn` to `myGrid.Tables(0)` so that your checkbox value is also bound. Then, apply your filter without calling `GetDataSet()` first.

Comment: Heres a working sample that simulates what I think you want: https://github.com/crowcoder/DGVFilter

Comment: @Crowcoder this line:  myGrid.DataSource = _gridData.GetDataSet()
is called just once at the form load, then rest in code ther are only filters as shown. In GetDataser method there is just sql query which getting result to object thats it. So question is when it's executed just once and then only Filters are used to me it does mean that filter is just working with current dataset and not quering itself database - please confirm that at the beggining. Does FilterRow quering database separatly or just quering current dataset without making additional query?

Comment: If that is being called only once then your problem must be that the CheckBoxColumn of the grid is not bound to the data table. If it is not bound the check will not persist after filtering.

Comment: @Crowcoder ok, but what about oryginal question does FilterRow/Sort will work on oryginal Datasource and itself not quering database itself?

Comment: RowFilter operates on the in-memory data, it does not know anything about the database.

Comment: @Crowcoder ok so it does mean it just operates on current datasource.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean by 'in-memory". Take a look at the sample I linked to - it creates a DataTable without any database.